# Java - set field given field's name in String

Tags: java, class, object, reflection

I have field's String name and I would like to set that field with other particular value.

I know that we can do that through reflection like [so](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-get-and-set-a-field-using-reflection.html):

```
DemoClass demo = new DemoClass();
Class demoClass = demo.getClass();

Field field = demoClass.getField("field1");
field.set(demo, "Hello");
```

Is there any other approach to NOT use reflection? The caveat is that we can't change class itself in anyway.

Comment: There is no built-in way to do this other than reflection. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, there may be a better alternative, but it would depend on writing code to support it.

Comment: `if(fieldName.equals("field1")) demo.field1 = "Hello"` or you could generate similar bytecode.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your *actual* task? Currently, you have just described the essence of Reflection (accessing a field by name `String`) and asked, how to do Reflection without Reflection.